# Wrong RGB values when modifying image with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Fairly new to C++ and I've been working with the OpenCV library. I'm attempting to create a dimming function for an image viewer. This is the main body of `void dim(int val)`.

I'm looping over every pixel, getting a reference to the RGB values of the pixel within a Vec3b then decreasing them by some change factor, calculated from `val / 255` (where `0 <= val <= 255`. But for some reason the `pix[0]` etc are all being set to 0, meaning that for any value of `val` the image turns black.

May be doing something slightly stupid with floating point here, or misunderstanding some aspect of OpenCV; but I can't see what it is.

```
for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
        Vec3b &pix = dst.at<Vec3b>(x,y);

        float change = val / 255.0f;
        pix[0] = (uchar)(pix[0] * change);
        pix[1] = (uchar)(pix[1] * change);
        pix[2] = (uchar)(pix[2] * change);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I test your code and it works fine! Don't set `val` too small, or the result `dst` will turns all black.

Comment: You can just do `dst *= val/255.0f`. Also, it looks like you have your indices wrong. You should have `x < cols` and `y < rows`.

Comment: Cheers for the heads up on that shorthand. I don't understand how the indices wrong though, the current configuration works fine and if I switch the variables over, it only dims a portion of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV has a doc about [changing the contrast and brightness of an image](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html). Generally speaking, it applys `alpha * pixel_value + beta` to every pixel. Since you only need to adjust the brightness of images, `alpha` can be set `1.0`. Here is the modified `dim()` function.

```
// negative beta dims image
void dim(Mat& src, Mat& dst, int beta) {
    for(int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++) {
            for(int channel = 0; channel < 3; channel++) {
                dst.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[channel] = saturate_cast<uchar>(src.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[channel] + beta);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Read what [saturate_cast](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html?highlight=saturate_cast#saturate-cast) does if interested.

To test the function above:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int beta;
    Mat src = imread(...);
    Mat dst = Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type());
    namedWindow("src", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("src", src);
    dim(src, dst, -200);
    namedWindow("dst", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("dst", dst);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply/divide integer value by real value less than 1 you'll get 0 because your scaling coefficient will be truncated to integer.
To correct your problem you should convert pix[] to float or double when scale it and convert result back to char.

Comment: I tried casting each pix[] value to float, but no difference.